# Open excel file in Python: XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to open an Excel file in Python, using:

```
import xlrd

loc = (r"C:\Users\my_path\my_file.xlsx")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
```

and it caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XLRDError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-b399ced4986e> in <module>
      4 loc = (r"C:\Users\my_path\my_file.xlsx")
      5 
----> 6 wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
      7 sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
      8 sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows, ignore_workbook_corruption)
    168     # files that xlrd can parse don't start with the expected signature.
    169     if file_format and file_format != 'xls':
--> 170         raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
    171 
    172     bk = open_workbook_xls(

XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have the right filename? It looks like you're trying to open a directory, rather than a specific Excel file within it; it would normally have an `.xls` or `.xlsx` extension... (or `.xlsm` or `.xlsb` etc).

Comment: Hi @sabik thank you for pointing out, please see the edited question.

Comment: Well now the error message tells you exactly what's wrong: "Excel xlsx file; not supported". Per the [homepage of the `xlrd` library](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it can only read "Excel files in the historical .xls format."

Comment: pass `engine="openpyxl"` to `pd.read_excel`.'

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang Thanks `pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\my_path\my_file.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")` worked !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The lastest version of xlrd is only support .xls file, so you can install the older version

```
pip uninstall xlrd

pip install xlrd==1.2.0
```

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use the openpyxl to do it.

```
pip install openpyxl
```

If you use it in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('file/path/to/excel/spreadsheet.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

If you don't specify the engine, it will use whatever default.